# Determine which properties in a class has a special attribute

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with some property like this:

```
public List<Some1POCO> SomeProp1List{ set; get; }

[SomeAttribute]
public List<Some2POCO> SomeProp2List { set; get; }
.
.
.
```

I want to find out properties that has "SomeAttribute" and then include this properties in a EF query

how to use it as a condition in LINQ queries ?

Comment: The answer is most likely yes.

Comment: take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.attributes?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

This example works if `TClass` has exactly one property with `SomeAttribute` and `TProp` is a reference type.

You can use this function in LINQ queries as you would with every other function.

```
TProp GetValueOfPropertyWithSomeAttribute<TClass, TProp>(TClass entity)
  where TClass : class
  where TProp : class
{
  return typeof(TClass)
    .GetProperties()
    .Single(pi => Attribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(SomeAttribute), false))
    .GetMethod
    .Invoke(entity, null) as TProp;
}
```

Comment: Should that be GetGetMethod() ?

Comment: I think GetMethod is fine (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod)

Comment: huh, fair enough!